# Cairo dock and unity

Tags: 13.10, cairo-dock

When I try to select a session for my cairo dock it only offers me Cairo dock(gnome) and the default Ubuntu session. I was wondering how do I get it to offer me Cairo dock with unity and the other sessions. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special session for running Cairo dock in Unity. Just log into Ubuntu and run Cairo dock from the dash.

[image]

The "Cairo dock (gnome)" session is just a gnome-fallback session with Cairo dock instead of the panels.